# how to send a value from textarea to file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this controller 
[image]

and this view 
[image]

How can I write to file what is the content of my `textarea` ?

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you post those image code in this question?

Comment: sry, I am new here

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your controller method name is "OpenFile", but in your view, you're calling for a Controller method name "GetFiles". That is one thing you need to fix.

Once that is in place, you can get the contents of your textarea by addressing the form:

var text = request.Form["TextAreaName"];